# Jquery:Keep unique Items in table row with minimum price?

Tags: jquery

In this bellow table, We can see two items TV and CAR with two different prices. I want display both two items with their minimum price without repeating duplicate items.

Sample Table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Items</th>
    <th>Price</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TV</td>
    <td>10000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>TV</td>
    <td>15000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>CAR</td>
    <td>750000</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>CAR</td>
    <td>450000</td>
  </tr>   
</table>
```

Target Table:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Items</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TV</td>
            <td>10000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CAR</td>
            <td>450000</td>
        </tr>   
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var item = {};
$(".myTable td:first-child").each(function() {
    var key = $(this).text();
    var val = $(this).closest("td").next().text();
    if (!item.hasOwnProperty(key) || item[key] - val > 0) {
        item[key] = val;
    }
});
var t ="<tr><th>Items</th><th>Price</th></tr>"
$.each(item, function(k, v) {
    t += "<tr><td>" + k + "</td><td>" + v + "</td></tr>";
});
$(".myTable").html(t);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/uknkS/

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most elegant way of doing this, but it accomplishes your goal in both IE 8 and Firefox:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cheapest = new Array();

    //Build cheapest array
    $('table tr').each(function(){
         var key = $(this).children('td:first-child').html();
         var value = $(this).children('td:last-child').html();
         if (key != null &&             //Verifies this is not the header
            (value < cheapest[key] || cheapest[key] ==null) ) {   
              cheapest[key] = value;
         }
    });

    //Hide the rows that don't match
    $('table tr').each(function(){
         var current_row = this;
         var key = $(this).children('td:first-child').html();
         var value = $(this).children('td:last-child').html();
         if( key != null && cheapest[key] != value ){
             $(current_row).hide();
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: cheapest is an object and so use `var cheapest = {};`

Comment: @naveen- can you describe/provide more info on the best practice? thanks

Comment: your code is fine. just asked you to declare `cheapest` as `Object`. http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/javascript-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

Here  you go

Working **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WLhkU/)**

```
$(function(){
   var $UniqueTds = []; 
    var $trs = $("table tr:gt(0)"); 

   $("table tr td:first-child").each(function(){
        if($.inArray($(this).text(), $UniqueTds) == -1){
            $UniqueTds.push($(this).text());
        }
   });

   var $tr = null; 
   $.each($UniqueTds, function(i, val){
       $tr = null;

       $trs.filter(function(){ return $(this).find("td:first").text() == val;})
           .each(function(){

               if($tr == null){
                   $tr = $(this);
               }
               else if(parseInt($tr.find("td:last").text()) < parseInt($(this).find("td:last").text())){
                       $tr = $(this);
               }
           });
           $tr.remove();
   });
});


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/WLhkU/
```